# How to make a stream to reply to twitter mentions with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I created a simple bot on twitter so that every time someone mentions my @ the bot will reply with a random phrase.

But it is not behaving as expected. It answers the first mention and then answers again the answer it provided.

I tried putting the parameter "exclude_reply_user_ids=bot_id"
but it still keeps replying to itself.

Please could someone help me?

```
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=bearer_token,
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)


class Tweetmentions(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.text)
        client.create_tweet(text=random_phrase(),
                            in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet.id,
                            exclude_reply_user_ids="bot_id"
                            )
        print('Successfully tweeted!')

stream_mentions = Tweetmentions(bearer_token=bearer_token)
stream_mentions.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("my_rule")) 
stream_mentions.filter()
```

[image]

Comment: maybe check what value you have in variable `bot_id` and what value has `id` in tweet. maybe you have wrong values.